# Как установить listener на CheckBox чтобы он вызывался на любое setSelected?

Tags: java, javafx

Есть `CheckBox`, когда он `false` нужно совершить какое-то действие (например задизэйблить какой-то другой компонент). Я попытался навесить на него соответствующий ***listener***

`checkBox.selectedProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> что-то делаем)`

Но проблема в том, что изначально (до `checkBox.setSelected(false)`, происходящего при открытии окна) значение и так `false`, и действие не выполняется, разумеется можно просто поставить проверку на checkBox после инициализации, но мне кажется логичнее как-то исправить мой ***listener*** чтобы он отрабатывал в любом случае.

Как это можно сделать?

Answer (score 1):

Нет, вам неправильно кажется. Лисенер как раз и нужен затем, чтобы при `взаимодействии` с этим чекбоксом делать какие-либо вещи. Если вам нужно дефолтное поведение - вы должны явно вызвать требуемое поведение.

как костыль можно вызвать `checkBox.setSelected(false)` после инициализации, и тогда лисенер *обнаружит* это взаимодействие и отработает

Answer (score 1):

Если нужно дизейблить компонент, то логичней использовать биндинг (описать состояние, а не поведение):

```
otherComponent.disableProperty().bind(checkBox.selectedProperty().not());
```

здесь `not()` добавлен чтобы инвертировать значение состояния чек-бокса

Answer (score 1):

Обычно после добавления листенера просто дергаю метод который вызывается внтри листенера. То есть

`checkBox.selectedProperty().addListener((ov, oldv, newv) -> doSmth(newv));
 doSmth(checkBox.isSelected());`